# NextJS add item to cart to woocommerce || how to set the same session

Tags: reactjs, next.js, woocommerce

Currently from my app nextjs i created add to cart, when I click on button the item is posted to woocommerce cart.

In woocommerce db i See correct this item is added to cart with session key: t_59fcbcadb97093b89c4096fab02bbf

But when I open cart in browser, I not see this items.
Of course, because when I open the browser, it is a different session than sending from the nextjs application.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this product appear in the cart? How can I set the same sessions for NextJS + WooCommerce applications as backend?

Maybe woocommerce create any cookies during click to add to cart, and I can do the same in NextJS so first retrive from API response session key, and then save as cookies and then when I open cart in woocommerce then this should read this cookies and display items? This is only my think, thanks for tips.